# React mapping items from object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react web app that is fetching a JSON object from my API on componentDidMount().

I am able to view the data in React dev tools in web browser but i am having trouble mapping the data to HTML. I have done it this way in previous applications but its not working with my current object.

I am sure there is a small problem with the syntax of how I am mapping the array. Thanks for the help.

[image of data object from react tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/738Og.png)

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class TeamInformation extends React.Component{
state = {teamNames: []}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedTeam: "none"            
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/users/teamNames')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(teamNames => this.setState({teamNames}));
}

render(){

return (
<div>
    <h1>Teams</h1>

{this.state.teamNames.map(teamData =>
    <div key={teamData.PK_TeamID}>
        <p>{teamData.cityName}</p>
    </div>
)}
</div>
)}}

export default TeamInformation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your attached image, the state `teamNames` is an object instead of array. You couldn't map an object, just change your code to this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedTeam: "none",
        teams: []            
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('/users/teamNames')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(teamNames => this.setState({teams: teamNames.teamData})); // teamData is an array, not teamNames
}

render(){
    ...
    {this.state.teams.map(team=>
        <div key={team.PK_TeamID}>
            <p>{team.cityName}</p>
        </div>
    )}
}
```

Comment: I changed it as you said to be:

render(){

return (
<div>
    <h1>Teams</h1>

{this.state.teamNames.teamData.map(team=>
    <div key={team.PK_TeamID}>
        <p>{team.cityName}</p>
    </div>
)}
</div>
)}}

But now it says: TypeError: cannot read property 'teamData' of undefined.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I have updated `constructor` and `componentDidMount`

Comment: @PringlerRushing does is help? Do you have any problem?